# J-S Divergence as a Percentage

Tags: probability, distributions, distance

Is there a way to interpret the Jensen-Shannon divergence which is normalized to be between 0 and 1 between two probability distributions as a "percent difference", i.e., there is a x% difference between the two probability distributions.

I am asking this possibly strange question because I have to use the J-S distance in a business application, and the audience which is non-technical understands percentages better than "distances". :)

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question, +1. Do you have a bunch of J-S distances in your presentation?

Comment: Yes, for example: 0.10389, 0.0897, etc...

Comment: One idea to consider is comparing all of the distances to some reference, maybe the biggest difference or the distance between to common distributions in your field.

Comment: okay, great, I can try that. Thanks.